# ng-model of <select> in a custom directive does not get saved in IE , works in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<form>
        <div ng-if="record.title" class="customClasses" ng-repeat="record in $.basevm.recordsperPage">
            <manycustomDirective data-record="record"></manycustomDirective>
        </div>
</form>
```

Multiple records are getting loaded using above custom directive and there are multiple pages.

This manycustomDirective.cshtml again has some more custom directive like below , which shows dropdowns using "select"

```
<single-choice ng-if="record.type == 1" data-record="record" ></single-choice>
<multi-choice ng-if="record.type == 2" data-record="record" ></multi-choice>
```

In single-choice directive's cshtml file , I have select + options

```
 <select class="customclassdeginedinLESS" ng-model="record.id" >
             <option value=""></option>
             <option value="{{choice.id}}" ng-repeat="choice in   record.choices">{{ choice.text }}</option>
         </select>
```

**Issue is**

For IE , only one value from all the pages and custom directives gets saved but in chrome and FF everything gets saved.

I tried using track by choice.id and track by $index but it didnt work.
Trying to write a listener on ng-change of select inside "link" function of CUSTOM directive , I assigned hardcoded value to scope.ngModel , but still it doesnt work.

```
     link(scope: any, element: any, attrs: ng.IAttributes) {

           scope.ngchangeListener= function (item) {

             scope.ngModel = '00000000';

          }
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for manycustomDirective? Your question is about an issue with <select> but there is not enough info to provide you an answer

Comment: @elliot-j , I edited my question above

Answer (score 0):

According to the angularJs document, there are some rules you should be aware of when using IE.

For more details, please see https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Comment: the link provided does not provide any guidance regarding issues with ng-select in IE

Comment: Well, if you can provide a Jsfiddle link, then I can help to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question I am assuming you want the following behavior: Display a `<select>` where each `record.type` is 1 that will allow a user to update the id for that record based on the `record.choices` available to it.

Please examine the following plunker to see if it resolves your issue.
When run in IE 11 (only version i have access to) modifying a `<select>` will update the `record.id` for the appropriate item

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/gyRDx2MRDyeVknS3Ladv?p=preview)

I atttempted to simplify the problem by removing references to your custom directives and swtiched from using an `ng-repeat` of `<option>'s` to using [ng-options](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/docs/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Assumed version of angular: 1.4.12